# Why do we lose geometric intuition regarding a scheme due to nilpotent elements?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have quite often read that the functor of points allows us to recover some geometric intuition for a scheme which was lost due to the presence of nilpotent elements in the structure sheaf.

I know this question is somewhat vague, but, regardless, what exactly is it about the nilpotent elements which don't allow us to view a scheme as a collection of points and how does the functor of points approach resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know very much algebraic geometry, so my understanding is that the functor of points view is a restatement of our notions of the points of a scheme and of what we think of as geometric intuition.

If $R$ is a ring with nilradical $J$, then for every ideal $I$ between $(0)$ and $J$, there is no difference between the underlying topological spaces $\textrm{Spec}(R/I)$ and $\textrm{Spec}(R)$.

More generally, if $X$ is a scheme, and $\mathscr J$ is the quasicoherent sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal O_X$ given by $\mathscr J(U) = \{ s \in \mathcal O_X(U) : s_x \in \textrm{Nil }\mathcal O_{X,x} \textrm{ for all } x \in U \}$, then for any quasicoherent sheaf of ideals $\mathscr I$ between $0$ and $\mathscr J$, there is no difference between the underlying topological spaces of the schemes $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ and $(X, \mathcal O_X/\mathscr I)$.

So it's not enough to view a scheme as a collection of points, i.e. as a topological space.  Instead, what we do is we use the functor of points view to change our definition of what are the points of a scheme.  And from this new definition of what is meant by "points," we are then changing what we mean by "geometric intuition."  And from this new notion of geometric intuition, we do recover everything there is to know about the scheme, by the Yoneda lemma.

Namely, if $Z$ is any scheme, we *define* the $Z$-points of $X$ to be the set $X(Z) = \textrm{Hom}_{\textrm{Sch}}(Z,X)$.  The functor $X(-): \textrm{Sch}^{\textrm{op}}\rightarrow \textrm{Set}$ then determines $X$ up to isomorphism, in the sense that if $Y$ is a scheme, then any isomorphism of functors $X(-) \rightarrow Y(-)$ (that is, any collection of bijections $X(Z) \rightarrow X(Z)$ for all schemes $Z$, natural in $Z$) determines an isomorphism of schemes $X \rightarrow Y$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X=Spec(k[x]/(x^2)$. There is only one prime ideal of $k[x]/(x^2)$ which is $(x)$. Hence $X$ consists of a single point, just like $Spec(k)$. The only difference between these schemes is that $X$ contains nilpotents in the structure sheaf but $Spec(k)$ does not.

Comment: Right. But how do we now use the functor of points to differentiate these two schemes?

Comment: @Jadwiga Maps from $Spec(k)$ into $X$ are points of $X$, while a map from $Spec(k[x]/(x^2))$ into $X$ is a point of $X$ along with a tangent vector based at the point. The idea here is that there’s some kind of “infinitesimal”  information encoded in the latter of these maps.

Comment: Hmm. I thought, using the functor of points, we were looking at the image of schemes mapping into $Spec(k)$ or $Spec(k[x]/x^2)$.

Comment: One way to think about this is that those two schemes can’t be the same because they don’t specify the same thing mapping into another space. If we look at $Hom(-,X)$, the functor of points for $X$, when evaluated on these two schemes, we get two different sets.